# ASP.NET 5 name confusion

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

If ASP.NET 5 is a new runtime that runs on both .NET Core and Full, then what should we call the current ASP.NET, or anything that depends on System.Web, when .NET 5 is released? I suppose ASP.NET 5 takes the number 5 from the next version of .NET, which will continue to include and support System.Web. Perhaps Classic ASP.NET?

---

@cecilphillip pointed out that the next version of .NET is 4.6, not 5. So, where does the 5 come from?

---

Historically, ASP.NET versions have been the same as .NET, as described on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd566231):

> - **ASP.NET 4.5.1** and Visual Studio 2013
>     Provides information about ASP.NET features in the **.NET Framework 4.5.1** and Visual Studio 2013.
> - **ASP.NET 4.5** and Visual Studio 2012
>     Provides information about ASP.NET features in the **.NET Framework 4.5** and Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.
> - **ASP.NET 4** and Visual Studio 2010
>     Provides information about ASP.NET features in the **.NET Framework 4** and Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.
> - **ASP.NET 3.5** and Visual Studio 2008
>     Provides a link to topics that describe ASP.NET features in the **.NET Framework 3.5** and Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition.

Comment: I have seen the term 'Classic ASP.NET` being used already in more than one place.

Comment: Simply using the framework and version on top of asp.net (vnext, mvc, webapi, etc) will more than likely be sufficient.

Comment: _"what should we call"_ - in which context?

Comment: @TravisJ Something like *.NET 5 WebForms*, *ASP.NET 5 WebForms*, *ASP.NET MVC 5*, *ASP.NET 5 MVC 5* ?

Comment: @MaxToro - The version will generally go with the framework version. So asp.net mvc 5 will more than likely be assumed to be using at least asp.net 4.5. asp.net mvc 6 would be assumed to be using asp.net 5 because that is the version which correlates to the release date. webforms, isn't that deprecated?

Comment: @TravisJ WebForms is not deprecated, see [this](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/aspnet-5-overview#webforms).

Comment: @MaxToro - Yes, it was in jest. I am not sure who is still creating new applications using webforms, but the two of them need to stahp.

Comment: .NET 5 is not being released. .NET 4.6 is getting released. ASP .NET 5 will run on 4.6 and .NET Core

Comment: @cecilphillip This is even more confusing than I thought. So, where does the 5 come from? Not MVC, not .NET. Perhaps ASP.NET 5 is planned to completely replace/deprecate System.Web on .NET 5?

Comment: the 5 comes from asp.net 5, which will run on .NET 4.5.1 that exists today, 4.6 that will be released this year, and also .NET Core that runs cross platform

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET version numbers are not tied to the .NET Framework version numbers. They may have been the same historically, but that doesn't mean there's any rule saying they had to continue to say the same, especially considering how out of band releases are being used.

ASP.NET 5 is the 5th major release of ASP.NET, hence the 5. ASP.NET 5 was previously called ASP.NET vNext.

The upcoming .NET Framework version is .NET 4.6. Obviously, Microsoft didn't feel enough had changed to warrant a major version number jump.

There is also a new type of framework called .NET Core. I don't think it will have traditional version numbers since it's composed of separate independently versioned packages. I have seen it said that Microsoft plans to have a "baseline" which is a set of specific versions of packages that they certify will work together.

Comment: Historically, ASP.NET versions have been the same as .NET, see [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd566231).

Comment: @MaxToro They were the same because of how ASP.NET had to be released with .NET, there were no out of band updates. So of course they happened to be the same historically. There was and is nothing else that ties them together.

Comment: I get it. So, the question remains, if ASP.NET 5 is the new framework, what do we call the old (System.Web) framework, specially when .NET 5 is released?

Comment: @MaxToro Well it's hard for me to predict the future. But I doubt they'll rename ASP.NET 5 to something else ex post facto. Logically, if there's a new version of ASP.NET, it'll be ASP.NET 5.1 or ASP.NET 6. And if there's a new version of .NET, it'll be .NET 4.6.1, or .NET 4.7, or .NET 5. Since they're not tied together, it makes perfect sense because they can increment them independently.

Comment: I understand they're not tied together, but both are using the same name.

Comment: @MaxToro What's using the same name?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder whether you are aware of the Python story,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)

where 2.* never go away (actively maintained), while new releases come from 3.*.

ASP.NET is on the same path, where

- Legacy web applications (WebForms and MVC) relying on System.Web won't disappear. If we look at classic ASP (longer than 10 years), there are still sites using it.
- Legacy web applications (Web API and SignalR) won't disappear.
- New web applications (purely based on ASP.NET 5 new interfaces) will rise.

Thus, Microsoft has to maintain two underlying platforms (or runtimes), aka

- .NET Framework 4.6 (and future releases) to support legacy applications primarily.
- .NET Core 5 (and future releases) to support new applications with cross platform features.

ASP.NET 5 is an application framework that luckily can sit both on .NET Framework 4.6 and .NET Core 5.

Tons of sessions can be found at [dotnetConf 2015](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2015) to cover those materials. So hope you can spare some time on them.

For legacy applications, you can still call them,

- ASP.NET 4 apps
- ASP.NET MVC 5 apps
- ASP.NET Web API 2 apps

and so on based on different contexts.

Comment: This is a good summary. Those videos from dotnetConf, Build, and TechEd really help you get a feel for these technologies, because it's very helpful to hear the devs discuss it with words, rather than trying to wrap your head around a technical document. My impression is that at some point (possibly several years away) .NET Framework will cease gaining new features and will only release security updates. I think the reason they haven't done that is that not everything has been migrated to .NET Core yet.